# How do I increase the infinity symbol in matplotlib labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the illustrative example below:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x=list(range(5))
xticks=x.copy()
xlabels=x.copy()
xlabels[-1] = r"$\infty$"

fig, axes = plt.subplots()

axes.plot(x)
axes.set_xticks(xticks)
axes.set_xticklabels(xlabels, fontsize=20)
```

This produces the following figure

[image]

I want to make the infinity sign larger in relation to the numbers in the x labels. It is too small in the way matplotlib plots it. Everything that I've tried to increase its size also increases the sizes of the numbers in the label.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, grab the last element in the xticklabels array and use set_fontsize on that element:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x=list(range(5))
xticks=x.copy()
xlabels=x.copy()
xlabels[-1] = r"$\infty$"

fig, axes = plt.subplots()

axes.plot(x)
axes.set_xticks(xticks)
axes.set_xticklabels(xlabels, fontsize=20)
axes.get_xticklabels()[-1].set_fontsize(26)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]